# Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)\cdot \sum _{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

We have $f:\left[0,\frac{\pi }{2}\right]\rightarrow R,\:f\left(x\right)=cos\left(x\right)$, and we need to evaluate:
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)\right)$.
Have any ideea how we can evaluate it?

Comment: Hint. $1 - f(n^{-1/2}) \sim 1/(2n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac 1n \cdot \left(f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)+ \ldots +f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)\right)
$$
is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ and the limit of
$$
  n \cdot \left(1-f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)
$$
can be calculated easily, for example with L'Hospital or using
the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, for your hint, maybe too visible, but no matter... I have another question: why in my book they said $\left(1-f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)=2sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)$ ? I want to understand why they did it ...which is the logic/reason? because I don't realize it if I should have to do this method

Comment: That follows from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae.5B19.5D.5B20.5D: $\sin^2(x/2) = (1 - \cos x)/2)$ . Perhaps the author thought that the reader is more familiar with the limit of $(\sin x)/x$ .

Comment: thank you Martin! but, after he said $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{sin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}\right)^{^2}=1$ and I think $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{sin\left(n\right)}{n}\right)=\infty $

Comment: @Lucas: Note that $1/(2 \sqrt n)$ tends to **zero** for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: so is not a general formula... how can I prevent such mistakes?

Comment: Recall in basic calculus that $(1-\cos x)/x^2 \to 1/2$ is an immediate consequence of $(\sin x )/x \to 1.$